# How can I align image horizontally in tailwind-css in Laravel breeze

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-breeze

I'm trying to align one omg with text, but the tag `<p>`breaks the line. I want to do something like this

[image]

But my code just does this

[image]

, soo that's my code:

```
       <div class="mb-10 mx-auto w-full max-w-sm fixed top-4 left-6 inline-block">
          <div >
            <a href="">
              <img src="../Assets/Img/logo.svg" class="h-10 w-10" alt="">
              <div class="space-y-2 text-left">
                <p class="font-bold text-purple-700 text-2xl">Vuexy</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the [`flex`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex) utility class to your `a` element.

```
<div class="mb-10 mx-auto w-full max-w-sm fixed top-4 left-6 inline-block">
  <a href="" class="flex">
    <img src="../Assets/Img/logo.svg" class="h-10 w-10 mr-4" alt="">
    <p class="font-bold text-purple-700 text-2xl">Vuexy</p>
  </a>
</div>
```